# Akka Java - Synchronous actors behavior design

Tags: akka, synchronous

I am new to AKKA. I'd like to design an application where several "agents” (the word agent is used to denote some intelligent entity, or a computer program) will execute the following instructions, for a fixed number of iterations:

1. send some meaningful information to a given subset of the other agents.
2. wait to receive an answer from all such agents.
3. perform some computation whose result depends on the received information.
4. Repeat the cycle from step 1.

These cycles should be executed in a synchronous fashion, and i would like to know what could it be a suitable design for such model in AKKA. 
I am currently using Java, and these agents may be distributed over several machines.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean "asynchronous"?

Comment: Hi. No, i meant "synchronous".

Comment: Ok, maybe Akka isn't right tool for you then as it is asynchronous by design. To achieve what synchronously should be straight forward without adding the complexity of a framework like Akka.

Comment: Is there any way I could use Akka Futures to get to my desired behavior?
And another question: Is there any java-based framework that you would recommend me for the above purpose, to avoid implementing the message-passing mechanism from scratch? Essentially, I would need to have control on when should my agent query its mailbox.

Comment: I think I understand a bit better what you are trying to achieve, but I am picturing it more as an asynchronous process in Akka where you have one actor that orchestrates the work with child actors and tracks whether they have completed their jobs or not by listening for a specific message to be returned from them containing the result. You could keep track of the results using some kind of collection and when all results received perform your computation and then the start the cycle again. You then have control over a single cycle running at a time but the message passing is all asynchronous

Comment: That is a nice solution. However i’m afraid about the network load overhead. 
Say that we have some actors A={a, b, c, …}, and let me denote with S_x the set of actors to whom the actor x has to communicate (send messages and receive back messages within a cycle), and with x’ the child of the actor x.
In this solution, at each cycle, an actor x has to spawn a child actor x' which need to perform its communications with the actors in S_x’ = {y’ | y \in S_x}. Thus, each child actor x’ needs to inform and needs to be informed about the new set S_x’. Unless there is a way to deterministically

Comment: know the ActorRef of a child Actor knowing the ActorRef of its parent (without explicit communication), this solution would produce an overhead of messages which is quadratic w.r.t. the number of agents and linear to the number of cycles.
This is because for each x, |S_x| could be |A| in the worst case.
Is there a way to avoid explicit communication of the new spawned children’s ActorRef (e.g., can an agent spawn a child multiple times, using the same ActorRef reference - so that the other agents can save such reference only once, at the beginning of the computation)?

Comment: sorry I got a bit lost in your description - however you can't spawn a child multiple times using the same ActorRef reference, but you could just create the child actors once and re-use them for each cycle. You mention network load overhead, are the actors therefore going to be distributed across a network? if they are in the same JVM then the communications between them doesn't involve the network so network load wont be a concern

Comment: In general they are distributed across a network. A last question (and thank you for all your comments!) - if i re-use the same child at each cycle, how would i let the child tell its parent that he's done with its own process (sending, and receiving messages), and then restart it again? Could you please provide me some pointers?

Comment: every child actor has a reference to it's parent via `getContext().parent()` so you just need to have a type of message that the child sends to inform the parent when it has completed it's processing. If the parent is supervising many child actors then you will obviously need to keep track of the status of each child in the parent